# Update Realm objects - SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, realm

I need to update all the objects in the database, when I try it, it says:

`Thread 1: "Attempting to modify a frozen object - call thaw on the Object instance first."`

I have the following:

```
@ObservedRealmObject var meal: MealTracking
@ObservedResults(MealTracking.self) var mealTracking
```

mealTracking is the one that contains everything and meal is the single object in the current view.

So once I update the name on that single object (meal), I want to update the name on all other objects. So I'm doing:

```
for (index, meal) in self.mealTracking.enumerated() {
    $mealTracking.wrappedValue[index].mealName = ""
}
```

and I get the error of not being able to update the objects.

I also tried it like `$mealTracking[index].mealName.wrappedValue = ""` and gives another error: `Referencing subscript 'subscript(_:)' requires wrapped value of type 'Results<MealTracking>'`

For a the single object on the current view I can update it with:

`$meal.mealName.wrappedValue = "some stuff"`, the problem is when attempting to update All objects

How can I update all the objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@ObservedRealmObject` is a frozen object. If you want to modify the properties of an @ObservedRealmObject directly in a write transaction, you must `.thaw()` it first.

In your case something like :

```
mealName.thaw()?.name = ""
```

More information :

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/swiftui/

https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/freeze-frozen-objects-and-thawing/15706/5

Comment: This is so weird, because I can update a single Binded object but not some object accessed by index... anyway I tried: `let realm = try! Realm()
            let newMeal = mealTracking[0].thaw()
            try! realm.write {
                newMeal?.mealName = "nop.."
            }`and I get an error: `Thread 1: "Cannot register notification blocks from within write transactions."`

Comment: @Arturo Please provide more code https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The code I provided should be sufficient, but I’ll include even more details, give me some time to put it up